# Comparing user id with user id from textfile

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to add user information and reject if user id already exists. Currently, my code displays "ID already Exists!" but still adds the user information.

this is my code:

```
String id = EditManagerID.getText();
String password = EditManagerPassword.getText();
String name = EditManagerName.getText();
String contact = EditManagerContact.getText(); 
String address = EditManagerAddress.getText();
String role = EditManagerRole.getText();   


try
{
    String reader;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ManagerDetails.txt"));
    while ((reader = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String[] split = reader.split(",");
        if (id.equals(split[0]))
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID already exists!", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}


if(id.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || contact.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || role.isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Fill In Everything!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}        

else
{

ClassUser u = new ClassUser (id, password, name, address, contact, role);

File f = new File("ManagerDetails.txt");


        try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true))){
            pw.println(u.toString()); //print into txtfile
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Added Successfully!");

        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

I tried to add an 'if-else' but not sure what to put as a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you 're saying if id already exists show message "ID already exists!" and then you continue adding users info anyway. 
In your if id already exists statement set a boolean variable **found** to true and then make one more if statement and check if found is true or false.

```
 boolean found = false;

 // ...

    if (id.equals(split[0]))
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID already exists!", "Warning", 
             JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
             found = true;
             //stop the while
             break;
        }

// ...

//check if id already exists or not. if not then add users info
if(!found){
      //put your adding users info code here
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it just adds the user infinitely.

Comment: thank you so much zach! i've been looking at my code for the past hour hhaha